# SnackBar goes behind other views

Tags: android

I am trying to show a Snackbar in my activity. But it is being shown behind other views in the activity. How to show it as a top view?

```
Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(referenceView, referenceView.getContext().getString(messageId), showLength);
snack.show();
```

`referenceView` is nothing but a label in the same activity.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your `referenceView` is instance of `CoordinatorLayout`, otherwise the Snackbar will anchor to a system view.

Per the [Snackbar docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html#make(android.view.View,%20int,%20int)) regarding the `view` parameter:

> Snackbar will try and find a parent view to hold Snackbar's view from the value given to view. Snackbar will walk up the view tree trying to find a suitable parent, which is defined as a CoordinatorLayout or the window decor's content view, whichever comes first.

Comment: This activity does not have a `CoordinatorLayout` element.

Comment: Then you can still surround the whole layout with a CoordinatorLayout, and your snackbar should appear where it's supposed to without touching any more code.

Comment: Did this solve your question? If so, please accept my answer. Thanks.